# When can I beat His Royal Ripeness?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I barely made it through the forced battle and he seems to have gotten significantly stronger now that he's just sitting around.  It does seem like I should be able to beat him without doing the actual mission, since he's not invincible, he's just very strong.

Should I just come back after I beat the game or is it feasible much earlier than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ridiculously hard to beat him without completing the quest first. It's also one of the seven paradox endings that can occur if you beat him once you have completed the game, thus it makes more sense to complete the mission to weaken him and then face him properly after game completion.

Comment: This is good and helpful (and so I've upvoted it) but it doesn't quite answer my question - assuming that I don't go out of my way to grind levels, am I likely to be strong enough to beat him before I finish the game or will it have to wait until I'm nearing maxed out stats?

Comment: It depends really. I still found him a decent enough challenge (though I didn't die) after having completed the game. I was 99 in main role and at least 50 in each of the others.

Comment: That clarifies it, thank you.  (Also, have you considered adopting a real account name? >.<)

Comment: I suppose I really should. user1016253 is so impersonable